# Forcing \overline not to continuously extend to adjacent variables

Tags: math-mode

Could someone kindly help me how I can correctly display the following formula?

```
(\pi\rho\overline{\Gamma_\theta}\overline{R_\theta}^2)
```

The output is shown below.

[image]

However, the overline should not be continuously extending over both `\Gamma_\theta` and `R_\theta`. I would expect something like the following, which is the edited version of the above picture using Microsoft Paint.

[image]

Comment: `\overline{\Gamma}_{\theta}\overline{R}_{\theta}^{2}`

Comment: I actually want to show that the averaging is on `\Gamma_\theta` and not on `\Gamma`. Please let me know of your thoughts.

Comment: You could insert a "thinspace", `\,`, between the two groups of variables. However, I think the expression looks a lot better if you do *not* extend the overline over the subscript `\theta`s, i.e., if you follow @egreg`s advice.

Comment: i think this looks better still: `(\pi\rho\overline{\Gamma_{\!\theta}} \,\overline{\!R_\theta}^2)` with a few more space adjustments.

Comment: Thank you @barbara beeton, @egreg, and @mico. Barbara's solution is exactly what I want. I also agree that @egreg's solution is simpler and nicer. It would be great to have your thoughts on what this `\overline{\Gamma}_{\theta}` implies? Does it imply averaging over `\Gamma` or `\Gamma_theta`?

Comment: not being a mathematician, i haven't the foggiest notion of what the notation means.  all i can say is that if the `\theta` is floating away from the `\Gamma`, it looks like it may be attached to/modify what follows.  here's the string i looked at to make the spacing appear sensible: `F_\theta \mathrm{F}_\theta + \mathit{\Gamma}_\theta \Gamma_\theta` where the latin `F` has the shape closest to `\Gamma`.  (as you may have guessed, i'm not delighted with the italic corrections on the upright cm caps, latin or greek; i suspect knuth doesn't use them with subscripts very often.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortening the overline on the right when a subscript is involved seems the best thing to do; it won't completely cover the subscript, but it doesn't seem really necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\average}[2][0]{{%
  \mspace{#1mu}%
  \overline{\mspace{-#1mu}\average@check#2\relax}%
}}
\newcommand\average@check[1]{%
  #1\@ifnextchar_{\average@sub}{}%
}
\newcommand{\average@sub}[2]{% #1 is _
  _{#2}\mspace{-2mu}\aftergroup\average@compensate
}
\newcommand{\average@compensate}{\mspace{2mu}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$(\pi\rho\overline{\Gamma_\theta}\overline{R_\theta}^2)$

$(\pi\rho\average{\Gamma_\theta}\average[2.5]{R_\theta}^2)$

$\average[2.5]{R}$

\end{document}
```

The optional argument is meant to shorten the overline on the left when the argument is slanted. The first line is the original `\overline`.

[image]

Comment: Errors and other odd things happen for `$\average{\mathrm{R}_\theta}$`.

Comment: @Dan Surely so; complex arguments like this should be input as `\average{{\mathrm{R}}_\theta}`. The alternative is to have separate macros for variable with or without subscripts.