# \overline with subscripts

Tags: subscripts, kerning

I would like to write

```
 \overline{Y}_n
```

in order to display the mean of Y. This yields:

[image: Overlined Y]

However when I do this there is a gap between the Y and the n. Using

```
\bar{Y}_n
```

yields:

[image: bared Y]

This avoids the gap however in that case the bar above the Y is not long enough for my liking.

I have seen that there exists a question [\overline and \widehat with subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151095/overline-and-widehat-with-subscript) but that question asks about subscript added to the bar symbol, not subscript added to the symbol(s) which are under the bar.

I'm also aware of this question: [Overline over a symbol with an index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211953/overline-over-a-symbol-with-an-index) but that question is about what you should or shouldn't do; not a method to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance!

EDIT: I realize that this question is very similar to this one: [Symbol with overline and subscript leads to wrong kerning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346842/symbol-with-overline-and-subscript-leads-to-wrong-kerning), however the answer given below is better than the ones to that question.

Comment: The simplest fix would be `\overline{Y}_{\!n}`, but it requires a little typing.

Comment: @Arzigoglu yeah they're quite similar, though I prefer the answer given below to this question, I'm not sure what the proper thing is to do in this case.

Comment: @hallomotocar you should see my answer more like a quick fix. If you want exact results (meaning same spacing as without the `\overline`), you should either use the answer provided in the question Arzigoglu linked to or use AboAmmar's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exact method with a `newcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mybar}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{$\phantom{#1}\overline{\phantom{#1}}$}#1}

\noindent
$Y_n$ ... with no bar \\    
$\mybar{Y}_n$ ... with my bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could insert a negative space `\!` to reduce the spacing:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\overline{Y}_n$\\
$\overline{Y}_{\!n}$\\
$Y_n$\\
$\overline{Y_n}$
\end{document}
```

[image]