# Non-combining \overline

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

In electrical engineering, when speaking of boolean algebra, it is common to represent negation (¬ P) with an overline and logical and (P ∧ Q) with juxtaposition. In LaTeX, I was using the `\overline` command in math mode for negation.

That worked well until I noticed that the lines over adjacent symbols were being combined. In HTML, this is like ¬ (P ∧ Q) becoming ¬ P ∧ ¬ Q, which is completely different.

As an example, consider this LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}

$\overline P \overline Q$

$\overline{P Q}$

$\overline P \ \overline Q$

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: LaTeX output]

`$\overline P \overline Q$` should look different from `$\overline{P Q}$`; the former should have two separate overlines and the latter should have a single overline that extends across both P and Q.

I can get close to what I want with `$\overline P \ \overline Q$`, but that has two problems. First, it introduces extra space between the P and the Q that wouldn't otherwise be there. Second, it requires manually and explicitly identifying how things should be placed on the page, which is difficult, error prone, and (as I understand) against the philosophy of TeX in that I'm supposed to worry about semantics while TeX handles the layout.

Note that I can't use `\bar`, because I often do need a single overline to stretch across both symbols (or even over a more complex sentence).

I'm guessing that the answer to my question is that I'm abusing `\overline`, and that I should instead be using some other math-mode command that is already defined in amsmath or even in LaTeX itself. In any case, I'm avoiding complex macros etc. because I very much doubt that they're the right choice here (or if they are, then there's already a package for it).

Lastly, I'll point out that very similar questions have been asked before, but I haven't found a satisfying answer to this one. In particular [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188416/forcing-overline-not-to-continuously-extend-to-adjacent-variables) is pretty much identical to mine, but the answer there is not without problems. I've described that solution along with a couple others in my answer below.

Comment: Why egreg's solution doesn't satisfy you? Have you tried `$\average[2.5]{P}\average[2.5]{Q}$`?

Comment: I agree with @CarLaTeX's comment: The `\average` macro prodived in @egreg's solution should work perfectly for you. I don't understand the basis for your claim that that solution "focuses on the subscripts". Indeed, it works equally well for expressions with and without subscripts.

Comment: CarLaTeX and Mico: Admittedly, I was too quick to dismiss egreg's solution; my claim that it only worked with subscripts was unfounded, and I've edited the question to address this. Nonetheless, I'm not happy with that solution, as I've described in the answer I just left. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\widebar` from `mathabx` without changing all the symbol fonts.

The code for importing the accent is taken (simplified) from [this answer by Leo Liu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16344/4427). I added a new macro to cope with the `amsmath` impossibility of dealing with nested accents where the inner object has two accented items. The optional argument to `\cwidebar` is used to fine tune the positioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{\mathalpha}{mathx}{"73}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cwidebar}[2][0]{{\mathpalette\@cwidebar{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\@cwidebar}[2]{\@cwideb@r{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\@cwideb@r}[3]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mkern-#2mu#3\mkern#2mu$}%
  \widebar{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\bar{P}\bar{Q}$
$\widebar{P}\widebar{Q}$
$\widebar{PP}\widebar{QQ}$
$\cwidebar[1]{\widebar{P}\widebar{Q}} \widebar{\widebar{R}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the case of a longer term, is it possible to make this `\widebar` or `\cwidebar` long enough? Consider `\widebar{x+y+z}`. I don't want to use `\overline` because it is thicker (or has another font) and is placed too far below (for example in `\overline{r}`).

Comment: @Thrash There's a maximum length, so no. With `unicode-math` you may get what you want, but it's a major step.

Comment: What could be a solution to my problem then? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633068/136549

Answer (score 1):

I have found three solutions to this question, and none of them are entirely
satisfactory. They are all implemented as macros. None are maintained or
packaged, to my knowledge.

### egreg's `\average`

Given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188433)

As pointed out in the comments to the question, egreg's `\average` command can
be used to solve this problem. It does two things. First, it trims the right
edge of the overline if it's over a subscript. Second, it provides a parameter
to manually trim the left edge of the overline.

#### Advantages

This solution works especially well if you have subscripts. It is the only
solution that trims the right edge of the overline when there is a subscript
there; the other solutions give overlines that extend as far right over a
subscript as plain `\overline` does, which some would say is too long.

#### Disadvantages

So-called "complex arguments" need extra curly braces. For example,
`\average{{\mathrm P}}` compiles but `\average{\mathrm P}` does not.

While the right-trimming of overlines with subscripts seems to work fine, this
question is about the trimming of overlines to separate them. In the case of
`\average`, this would be done with the argument, making it a manual and tedious
process. The amount to trim the overline depends on the font and its slant.
Furthermore, this only trims the left edge, so there is no way to handle upright
text; `\average[2.5]{{\mathrm P}} \average[2.5]{{\mathrm Q}}` is clearly
lopsided.

### Enrico Gregorio's `\closure`

Given in an email available
[here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/n8o-oaWZ8bI/B0Ll6BnGI1IJ)

This solution seems pretty much identical to egreg's, with the following
differences.

#### Advantages

Unlike egreg's, this solution does not require extra braces for "complex
arguments".

#### Disadvantages

Unlike egreg's, this solution doesn't right-trim the overline for subscripts.

It handles left-trimming the same way as egreg's solution, except that the
argument defaults to 3 instead of 0. This carries all of the same problems
(completely manual, not useful with upright characters).

### Hendrik Vogt's `\widebar`

Given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253)

#### Advantages

Mostly-intelligent placement of the overline. It seems to do the right thing
in pretty much all cases I could think of that don't involve nesting.

#### Disadvantages

It incorrectly combines "outer" overlines when nesting is involved. For
example, `$\widebar{\widebar P \widebar Q} \widebar{\widebar R}$` looks like
it has a single bar that extends across the whole thing. Of course, this pretty
much defeats the point in this case.

Unlike egreg's solution, this also doesn't trim the right edge of the overline
with subscripts.

### The mathabx package's `\widebar`

This was apparently the inspiration for Vogt's `\widebar`. It seems to be just
as good except it doesn't have the same nesting problem. I don't think mathabx
is compatible with amsmath, though.

---

For the moment, I'll probably be using Gregorio's `\closure`.

If anyone comes up with more information or a better solution, please let us
know. I find this answer disappointing, and I'd love to accept a
different one.

Comment: It should come to no surprise that solutions from the same person are alike. There is no incompatibility between mathabx and amsmath, because they do very different things; the main problem is that mathabx changes all symbols. It's easy, though, importing just a few symbols, for instance `\widebar`.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose I reccomend trying `\,` between characters.

For example, `$\overline{P}\,\overline{Q}$`.

This creates a small, nonbreaking space between the characters which is enough to separate the overlines. It does create a very small space between the characters but not so much as to look unnatural.

I tried the `\widebar` described above and found that this undesirable for two reasons - first, they did not cover the whole letters, and secondly when zooming in the bars remained very small.

Answer (score 1):

This does not change the character spacing at all, but rather just shrinks the overline by 1mu on both ends.  I call it `\ncoverline` to denote "non-combining".

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ncoverline[1]{\mkern1mu\overline{\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-1mu}\mkern1mu}
\begin{document}
$PQ$

$\ncoverline P \ncoverline Q$

$\ncoverline{P Q}$

$\overline{P Q}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Might be a dirty hack but it works really well. Should be the accepted answer. @alex-robbins