# Widebar and superscript

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents

This is a question that arose from using [Hendrik Vogt's \widebar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/44848). I noticed that superscripting a `widebar` letter raises the superscript. Is there any way to make the superscript stay in the original height? (And is it bad syntax to do so?)

```
\widebar{\mathbb R}^2 \quad \mathbb R^2 
\quad 
\widebar R^2 \quad R^2
```

[image: Superscripted R]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Hendrik's answer %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
    \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
    \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
}
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
        %Enable nesting of accents:
        \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
        %If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
        \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
        %Determine the italic correction:
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
        \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
        \dimen@\wd\tw@
        \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
        %Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
        \divide\dimen@ 3
        \@tempdima\wd\tw@
        \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
        %Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
        \divide\@tempdima 10
        \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
        %Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
        \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
        %The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
        \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
        \if#31
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
        \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
        %Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
        \let\final@kern#2%
        \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
        \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
        \else
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
        \fi
    }%
    \macc@depth\@ne
    \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
    \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
    \macc@set@skewchar\relax
    \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
    %The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
    \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
    \else
    %If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
    %a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
    \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% End Hendrik %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
$
\widebar{\mathbb R}^2 \quad \mathbb R^2 
\quad 
\widebar R^2 \quad R^2
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: make a new macro that does `\widebar{#1}\vphantom{#1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `\smash[t]{...}`, or adding a pair of braces before the exponent:

```
\documentclass[preview, border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Hendrik's answer %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
    \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
    \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
}
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
        %Enable nesting of accents:
        \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
        %If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
        \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
        %Determine the italic correction:
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
        \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
        \dimen@\wd\tw@
        \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
        %Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
        \divide\dimen@ 3
        \@tempdima\wd\tw@
        \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
        %Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
        \divide\@tempdima 10
        \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
        %Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
        \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
        %The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
        \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
        \if#31
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
        \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
        %Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
        \let\final@kern#2%
        \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
        \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
        \else
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
        \fi
    }%
    \macc@depth\@ne
    \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
    \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
    \macc@set@skewchar\relax
    \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
    %The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
    \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
    \else
    %If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
    %a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
    \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% End Hendrik %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

$ \smash[t]{\widebar{\mathbb R}}^2\quad\widebar{\mathbb R}{}^2\quad
\widebar{R}{}^2 \quad \mathbb R^2\quad R^2 $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that the superscript is set dependent on the height of the prior token. You could tell LaTeX that the token has the height 0pt using `\smash` or use `\vphantom` to let the token prior to the superscript have the height of the content without `\widebar`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Hendrik's answer %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
    \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
    \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
}
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
        %Enable nesting of accents:
        \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
        %If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
        \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
        %Determine the italic correction:
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
        \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
        \dimen@\wd\tw@
        \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
        %Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
        \divide\dimen@ 3
        \@tempdima\wd\tw@
        \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
        %Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
        \divide\@tempdima 10
        \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
        %Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
        \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
        %The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
        \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
        \if#31
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
        \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
        %Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
        \let\final@kern#2%
        \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
        \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
        \else
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
        \fi
    }%
    \macc@depth\@ne
    \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
    \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
    \macc@set@skewchar\relax
    \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
    %The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
    \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
    \else
    %If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
    %a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
    \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% End Hendrik %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*{\widebarpot}[2]{%
  \smash{\widebar{#1}}^#2}% or \widebar{#1}\vphantom{#1}^#2

\begin{document}
$
\widebar{\mathbb R}^2 \quad \mathbb R^2 
\quad 
\widebar R^2 \quad R^2
$\\
$
\widebarpot{\mathbb R}{2} \quad \mathbb R^2 
\quad 
\widebarpot{R}{2} \quad R^2
$
\end{document}
```

Using `\smash`:
[image]

Using `\vphantom`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is really funny to me that I did not consider using `\vphantom` as I actually fiddled with it to increase the border height of the example (but ended up using rule). I did not know `border` was an optional argument to `standalone`. Two things learned from one question!

Answer (score 1):

**Acc** (for accented) atoms will be considered, as far as their height is concerned, equal to their base. The construction of the wide bar “by hand” does not make an **Acc** atom, so the whole box is used for determining the height.

If you're not in shortage of math families, I suggest using `\widebar` from `mathabx` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364929/4427 for the source and for another application).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{\mathalpha}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

$
\bar{\mathbb{R}}^2
\quad
\mathbb{R}^2
\quad
\bar{R}^2
\quad
 R^2
$

$
\widebar{\mathbb{R}}^2
\quad
\mathbb{R}^2
\quad
\widebar{R}^2
\quad
 R^2
$

\end{document}
```

[image]