# power and alignment

Tags: alignment, size

The following code

```
$X^D \overline{X}^D$ Versus $X^{^D} \overline{X}^D$
```

gives
[image]

I would like to have alignment and same size of D.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: `\bar{X}` will do, with a more elegant output.

Comment: While I agree with the suggestion by @egreg, a possible alternative is `$X\vphantom{\overline{X}}^D$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid `\overline`: `\bar` is more elegant. If you really think it's too short, you may try `\widebar` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391193/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% for \widebar
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{\mathalpha}{mathx}{"73}

% fixed overline
\newcommand{\foverline}[1]{\smash[t]{\overline{#1}}\vphantom{#1}}

\begin{document}

Bar: $X^D+\bar{X}^D$

Widebar: $X^D+\widebar{X}^D$

Overline: $X^D+\foverline{X}^D$

\end{document}
```

[image]