# Decrease spacing between double bars

Tags: math-mode, typography, accents, text-decorations, bar

I'd like double bars over my X, that I can get using these overline symbols

```
\[\overline{\overline{X}}\]
```

I also tried the bar symbols, but they're misaligned over the X.

```
\[\bar{\bar{X}}\]
```

What I end up with is two bars, but the spacing seems too large between the bars. How do I decrease the spacing with double bars?

[image]

Comment: You can see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364929/4427 for using `\widebar` from `mathabx`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general version that works across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newcommand\doverline[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\overline{#1}$}%
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-.15ex\relax% CHANGE .15 TO AFFECT SPACING
  \overline{\copy0}%
}}

\begin{document}
$\overline{X} + \doverline{X}$

$\scriptstyle\overline{X} + \doverline{X}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\overline{X} + \doverline{X}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only require it in `\displaystyle`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\doverline[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\overline{#1}$}%
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-.15ex\relax% CHANGE .15 TO AFFECT SPACING
  \overline{\copy0}%
}

\begin{document}
$\overline{X} + \doverline{X}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: And I wanted to put an answer like this one :-) much primitive :-) `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\dbar}{\rotatebox{90}{$\parallel$}}
\newcommand{\dsbar}{\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle\parallel$}}


\begin{document}

\[ \overset{\lower.1em\hbox{\dbar}}{X},\quad  \scriptstyle{\overset{\lower.1em\hbox{\dsbar}}{X}}\]
\end{document}`

Comment: @Sebastiano As they say, there are many ways to skin a cat!

Comment: It is absolutely true. But I wanted to beat you ahahahah. My regards.