# \overline, \bar, \widebar: using the style of \bar, but making it longer

Tags: bar, overline

I prefer `\bar` over `\overline` because of two reasons: `\overline`

1. places the line too far below, consider for example `\overline{r}`.
2. has a thicker line than `\bar`, possibly it's even a different font.

But one disadvantage of `\bar` is the length of the line, which is often too short, consider for example `\bar{M}`. However, I've come across this wonderful solution, which I think uses the same font/thickness and almost the same placement as `\bar`:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16344/136549

But even so, the line of `\widebar{x+y}` is still too short. How can I make it long enough while using the style of `\bar`?

Consider the equation `\overline{r}=\overline{x+y}`. I want the lines to be a bit higher and thinner like in `\bar{r} = \bar{x+y}`, where the line on the right side is merely too short. The solution `\widebar{r} = \widebar{x+y}` is not bad, but the line is still not long enough.

Can the style and the placement of `\overline` be modified so that it behaves like `\bar` (but draws long lines)? This would allow me to combine the respective advantages of both commands.

Comment: Did you try with `mathabx`?

Comment: Yes, the same. The code of `\widebar` I'm using so far and to which my link refers is precisely an extract from mathabx.sty and mathabx.dcl.

Comment: What's so bad about `$\overline{x+y\mathstrut}$`?

Comment: Consider the equation `\overline{r}=\overline{x+y}`. I want the lines to be a bit higher and thinner like in `\bar{r} = \bar{x+y}`, but stretch the line on the right side of the latter.

Comment: If you want the line drawn by `\overline` to be placed a bit higher up, give `$\overline{x+y\vphantom{k}}$` a try. It won't address the line thickness issue, though.

Comment: Can the style and the placement of `\overline` be modified so that it behaves like `\bar`? This would allow me to combine the respective advantages of both commands.

Answer (score 5):

The wide math accents in legacy TeX fonts have a maximum width.

If you're willing to go with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\[
\wideoverbar{b}+\wideoverbar{a+b}+\wideoverbar{a+b+c}+\wideoverbar{a+b+c+d}
\]

\[
\overline{b}+\overline{a+b}+\overline{a+b+c}+\overline{a+b+c+d}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]